# Create an app that will scan barcode in a loop until the device's battery level is depleted

Tags: barcode, zxing, monitor, barcode-scanner, battery

I need to create an app that will scan a barcode continuously until the battery level of the device is low to the point where it turns off. I need to test how long the battery will last while scanning barcodes. I need to collect the data of the barcode type, the barcode number, the time of duration to scan the barcode, and the battery percentage at each scan.

I am new to programming with Android and will appreciate all the help I can get!
So far I have modified the ZXing Barcode Scanner app and it will print the barcode type, barcode number, time of duration for one single scan, but I need to save these values as well as add in the battery component. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to use this for testing and not release on Market, I think it may be easiest to modify the Barcode Scanner source to do what you say here. You can disable its automatic shutdown timer in the code, and log whatever you want with each scan.